# Mysql compare values in two rows that belong to the same ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql table and would like to retrieve only those `post_id`'s where the current day lies between the `meta_value` of `start_date` and `end_date` (formatted as `mmdd`). So as of today (October 10th) only post_id 11 would be returned.
How can I make this comparison of two rows (start and end date) that belong to the same post_id??

Please help me out!

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ post_id ║   meta_key    ║ meta_value ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║ 10      ║ start_date    ║ 0101       ║
║ 10      ║ end_date      ║ 1231       ║
║ ...     ║ ...           ║ ...        ║
║ ...     ║ ...           ║ ...        ║
║ 11      ║ start_date    ║ 0101       ║
║ 11      ║ end_date      ║ 0131       ║
║ ...     ║ ...           ║ ...        ║
║ ...     ║ ...           ║ ...        ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Why isn't it start_date_date?

Comment: just a simple advice but, it is nicer to keep a primary key **unique** . also, try **subquerying**.

Comment: @Gokigooooks The primary key *is* unique. The PK in this instance would be (post_id,meta_key)

Comment: this is a wordpress wp_postmeta table, so i can't mess with that and have to agree with @Strawberry

Comment: what value does the post_id hold? just askin

Comment: @Gokigooooks The post_id presumably holds the post_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JOIN` in query:

```
SELECT t1.post_id
  FROM table_name t1
  JOIN table_name t2 ON t2.post_id = t1.post_id
 WHERE t1.meta_key = 'start_date'
   AND t2.meta_key = 'end_date'
   AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') BETWEEN t1.meta_value AND t2.meta_value
```

Why `JOIN` - because we need compare values from two different rows in table (one with `meta_key = 'start_date'` and other `meta_key = 'end_date'`).

Comment: This should possibly be a LEFT JOIN - to allow for undefined end dates

Comment: there are no undefined end dates. the dates represent the seasonal availability of a product, hence there is no year.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple if I understand what you're asking (would be easier with actual data) -

```
SELECT `post_id`
FROM `table`
WHERE `meta_value` BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date' -- supply actual dates here
```

Comment: I still think you've oversimplified the problem - but let's see what the OP says.

Comment: thx, but this is the actual data. the actual start_date and end_date are supplied in the meta_value column. so i guess ur solution won't work.

Comment: What is the data type of column meta_value @user3200582?

Comment: I know its formatted that way, but what is the type? VARCHAR? CHAR? INT? The reason that I ask is because calcing dates without a date format is particularly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav_hell;

CREATE TABLE eav_hell
(post_id INT NOT NULL
,meta_key    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,meta_value DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO eav_hell VALUES
(10      ,'start_date',20140101),
(10      ,'end_date',20141231),
(11      ,'start_date',20140101),
(11      ,'end_date',20140131);

SELECT x.post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'start_date' THEN meta_value END) start_date
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'end_date' THEN meta_value END) end_date
  FROM eav_hell x
 GROUP 
    BY post_id
HAVING STR_TO_DATE('20140201','%Y%m%d') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;

+---------+------------+------------+
| post_id | start_date | end_date   |
+---------+------------+------------+
|      10 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
+---------+------------+------------+

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b38347/2
```

Comment: thx for that solution. In terms of speed, do u think there is any advantage over the solution by Rimas?

Comment: If anything, Rimas's solution should be fractionally faster! I just think this one looks a little cleaner.

Comment: thx for ur answer, would like to push it but can only give one solution checkmark